# Upper case letters in a URL, should it be advertised that way?

Tags: apache, url, semantics, uppercase

Currently, our URL's look something like this:

```
http://helpdesk.ourdomain.com
```

Recently, there has been talk of advertising these URLs (in publications, on websites, etc.) to look like this for readability purposes:

```
http://HelpDesk.OurDomain.com
```

Our web server handles going to the URL with upper-case elements in it correctly, meaning when you go to that URL, it rewrites the URL to be all lower-case. However, I was always taught that URL's are meant to be case-sensitive. Keeping that in mind, I would think that advertising the URL's with upper-case letters would not be something that should be done.

Is advertising URL's with upper-case letters in it an okay practice? Why or why not?

Comment: The host name is case-insensitive. User agents usually turn them into lower case before requesting the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html):

> URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive.

I would say not, keep it lowercase.

Comment: The pragmatic version is that the hostname, and only the hostname, is case-insensitive in general: In this case, the part between `http://` and the first `/` after that. If you're truly convinced that usability will be improved, feel free to mess with the case of the hostname. But really, don't do that unless there's a strong argument against all lower case. It's a style that hurts the eyes of many a nerd (self included) and will make novices think the extra shift-pressing is necessary, which depending on the environment may be an even bigger usability issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html):

When comparing two URIs to decide if they match or not, a client SHOULD use a case-sensitive octet-by-octet comparison of the entire URIs, with these exceptions:

```
  - A port that is empty or not given is equivalent to the default
    port for that URI-reference;

    - Comparisons of host names MUST be case-insensitive;

    - Comparisons of scheme names MUST be case-insensitive;

    - An empty abs_path is equivalent to an abs_path of "/".
```